# How to prevent to exposing business logic when using firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

I know all of APK could be decompiled and reverse engineered. Actually I've done this for studying purposes.

So when I use firebase cloud storage and firebase firestore. It should be included in my android project as a SDK and It means all of code that using firebase possible to be exposed.

Every query using firestore would be exposed otherwise I use REST API(like firebase cloud function) then It wouldn't be possible.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I would suggest you to use firebase security rules and firebase cloud function for sensitive task.

Comment: @AlifHasnain firebase security rules seems just a some kind of ACL like firewall so It can't be secure the source code.

Comment: It is not possible to protect your code from reverse engineering. All you can do is to use proguard to make it hard to reverse engineer your code.

Comment: @AlifHasnain Then who use firebase as a mobile backend? and why? I'm really confused.

Comment: Your code can be exposed doesn't mean that firebase is not secured. As I said with the help of firebase security rules you can define who can access which data and also to run sensitive query or other sensitive operation with firebase cloud function. Do not do something in your client code which can be used to get sensitive data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The business logic in an application that uses Firebase is typically spread out over these places:

1. In your application code.
2. In your server-side code.
3. In your security rules.

Most of your logic should be in the application code. I highly recommend making that your default choice: add the functionality directly in to your application.

If your code *is* secret or *uses* secrets, move that into a trusted environment, such as your development machine (which you often use for given your team's user account a custom claim to make them admins), a server you already control, or Cloud Functions. In the last two cases, you'll often invoke that server-side code from within your app in some way, so you need to think about how to secure access so that only authorized users can run it (e.g. your team members who's auth account has an admin claim).

The final place you'll see business logic is in your security rules. There's often a split between business logic in rules and in server-side code, but you'll often see that you're rebuilding business logic that is in the client into the server too, either as server-side code, as security rules, or a combination of the two.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firebase Cloud Functions for business logic you feel is sensitive and shouldn't be written at the client side(Android app). To make it harder to reverse engineer you can also take a look at obfuscating your android application from the Android Documentation here [Shrink, obfuscate, and optimize your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code)

Obfuscating shortens the name of classes and members making it hard for anyone who decompiles your apk to reverse engineer it. An example is when you try going through the source code of libraries(Eg. FirebaseAuth), method names and variable names have been replaced with zza, zzb etc